# Zend Session saves in the right path, but gc try to clean elsewhere

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

My Project is running under ZF 1.11, and it throws this error randomly:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:469): Error #8 session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/tmp) failed: Permission denied (13) Array' in /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Session.php:482 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true) 
#1 /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Dlx/Acl/Permissao.php(8): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('user_info') 
#2 /home/user/www/MyProject/application/Bootstrap.php(72): Dlx_Acl_Permissao->__construct(Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)) 
#3 /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initLoaders() 
#4 /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('loaders') 
#5 /home/user/ in /home/user/www/MyProject/library/Zend/Session.php on line 482
```

As you can see, it tries to clean the session in /tmp directory, but in my application.ini the configuration sets session.save_path to APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session" (ZF default conf), and it saves the session in this path, but when gc runs, it tries to clean in the wrong directory

This is my application.ini session configuration:

http://codepad.org/mJUyipG0

Btw, /data and /data/session permission are set to 777

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini `/tmp` seems top be the default directory for php session saves. Although in my installation the save path line is commented out. `;session.save_path = "/tmp"`

You can also debug by dumping `Zend_Session::getOptions();` (*it is a static method*) to make sure your parameters are being correctly set.

This might be the cause of the exception:

> **string save_path** - The correct value is system dependent, and should
>   be provided by the developer using an **absolute path** to a directory
>   **readable and writable by the PHP process**. If a writable path is not
>   supplied, then Zend_Session will throw an exception when started
>   (i.e., when start() is called).

Hopefully it's this simple, just supply an absolute path and check permissions.

The `..` in the path may be the problem. `APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"`

Comment: Here is the output for var_dump: http://codepad.org/lkmOxIFm . Apparently the settings are ok